# jquery how to observe any change in the dom for a specific selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that looks for the existence and count of the class .dirty on a webpage. It would have to start at a certain point but at that point, I'd like for jQuery to observe for css changes in the DOM and rerun this function. Is this possible? Could I use `on()` for this? Like:

```
$(document).on('change','.dirty', dosomething);
```

although I know that's different than what change is used for. Basically, the change I want is any `addClass` or `removeClass` for '**dirty**'.

**sample markup**

looking for observing both adding / removing .dirty on 'top-level-menu' so that I can propogate change

```
<div class="top-level-menu dirty" data-menu-global-id="12828">
  <input id="menu-name-global-id-12828" size="30" type="text" value="Some value here">
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no method to do that nowadays. Instead - you probably would create your custom event and build your solution over it.

Comment: I think what you are looking for has been answered here:


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener
  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154882/how-can-i-observe-the-contents-of-an-a-tag-jquery

Comment: @UmairP - looks ugly, saw one of those but thought there would be a nicer sol'n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.on would be perfect for this function, however I would try to be a little more specific about  where you are expecting ".dirty" to happen. For example, if you know that dirty will only happen in the nav, only watch nav.

```
$('nav').on('change', '.dirty', function(e) {
    doSomething(e); 
});
```

View the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjoshuanoah/TvYG4/2).

Comment: thx, hmm... tried this before and wasn't working; not sure if this is supported

Comment: Yeah, I've used it before, and worked fine. Could you post your code and I'll make a js fiddle for you?

Comment: @timpone jsFiddle link added.

Comment: @BrianNoah  OP is looking for a DOM listener so if `$('.dirty).css(.. ` makes a change the listener would catch the change. There are no such listeners in jQuery without triggering a custom event from the code that makes the change